# Where to store longer Oauth Access Tokens?

Tags: managed-package, oauth2, customsetting, namedcredentials, accesstoken

We are implementing a Custom OAuth flow not using `NamedCredentials` and `AuthProviders`. For the storage of the Access Token we planned on using a Protected Custom Setting modified by an LWC component (this is part of a Managed Package).

Are longer tokens recommended and improve security? I couldn't find a clear statement about that online (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/8098515/1388807).

**Is that true? Where can we instead safely store the token? A Custom Metadata Type?**

Comment: Salesforce does recommend CMT over (list) custom settings, viewing the former as a replacement for the latter. Note, however, if you do use a custom metadata type to store these your org will list a deployment each time you persist one of these tokens to a CMT record because of the way the built-in apex Metadata API works.

Comment: One of the drawbacks of using CMT is, the user running the OAuth flow will need MDAPI access to create the CMT record(standard users usually don't have this access).

As a workaround, you can create multiple fields of 255 characters each in a protected custom setting and split a long access token in all fields, and concatenate values from those fields whenever you need to read it

Maybe, create a Class Token.write(String largeCharacter) and Token.read() to abstract the complexity

Comment: @AnmolKumar would you mind adding that great workaround as a real answer please?

Answer (score 5):

In one of our projects, we used a Hierarchy Custom Setting with three fields to split the token and store it as fragments in those fields-

This custom setting is saved as an instance using the user Id to fetch the instance itself.

[image]

The main idea is to get by user (through an API wrapper) the token instance to avoid having to call OAuth API every time an API is needed. If the token becomes invalid, the wrapper will know it will have to call the OAuth API, and the process is saved and restarted for the given user.

[image]

Comment: A caution; AFAIK it is not possible to create a hierarchy custom settings for a community user, only Salesforce and Salesforce Platform users.

Comment: Good point Phil, for that one then yes, you will have to deploy (since no longer present on UI) the customSettingType as List and play with another field as identifier for the upsert operation

Comment: @RaulPereyra could you add that to your answer please? Any maybe also refactor the second sentence as I am not fully understanding. ;-)

Comment: Updated answer @RobertSösemann

Comment: We have used this pattern many times on projects where we needed to store tokens longer than 255 chars. We abstract the splitting and storage mechanism away via apex methods in a service class that store and retrieve from the protected custom setting so that the caller does not need to be concerned with more than a `getToken` or `setToken` level of interaction.